# I want to ask the value for c from the user after the print statements not before them. How to do it?

Tags: plsql

This program is asking the values of a,b and c and then printing the print statements. I want to ask the value of c before printing the print statements.

```
set serveroutput on;
set verify off;

DECLARE
a number=&a;
b number=&a;
c number;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Press 1 for ADDITION');
dbms_output.put_line('Press 2 for SUBTRACTION');
dbms_output.put_line('Press 3 for MULTIPICATION');
dbms_output.put_line('Press 4 for DIVISION');
c:=&choice;
END;
```

Comment: could you please give more information about this issue?, its a big pain try to understand this

Comment: @Ethaan if you execute this code , the following steps occur (1)it asks for the values of a,b,c (2)it prints the put line statements.I want it to (1) ask the values of a and b (2) print the putline statements (3) ask the value for c

Answer (score 0):

Your substitution variables will be processed first, then the PL/SQL block will be run.

You could use [ACCEPT and PROMPT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12005.htm) SQL*Plus commands, but note that are SQL*Plus commands, not PL/SQL and will not work under other environments except SQL*Plus.

```
set serveroutput on;
set verify off;

accept v_num_a prompt 'Enter value of a: '
accept v_num_b prompt 'Enter value of b: '

prompt 'Press 1 for ADDITION'
prompt 'Press 2 for SUBTRACTION'
prompt 'Press 3 for MULTIPICATION'
prompt 'Press 4 for DIVISION'

accept v_choice;

DECLARE

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Numbers entered: ' || &v_num_a || ' ' || &v_num_b || ' choice: '|| &v_choice);
END;
```