# Get input from user in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm building a procedure which would require to get an input from user to print few details. But when I use & to get values it fails with errors. the logic is as follows..

```
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter Y to display Unauthorized records OR N to skip the display');
--SELECT &1 INTO lv_choice FROM DUAL;
IF NOT ('&lv_choice'='Y') THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('RECORDS WILL NOT BE DISPLAYED');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('RECORDS TO BE DISPLAYED ARE:');
......
```

I have tried using &1 into dual or directly calling &lv_choice which is failing with PLSQL internal errors.

Any methods to get input from user to proceed further in the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using some UI Terminal like SQLDeveloper or TOAD, you can achieve it using below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE INPUTPROCEDURE (LV_CHOICE IN VARCHAR2)

AS
BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter Y to display Unauthorized records OR N to skip the display');
--SELECT &1 INTO lv_choice FROM DUAL;
IF lv_choice <> 'Y' THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('RECORDS WILL NOT BE DISPLAYED');
ELSE
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('RECORDS TO BE DISPLAYED ARE:');

END INPUTPROCEDURE;
```

And Invoke the above Procedure like below:

```
DECLARE
 dyn_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
 b        BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
 dyn_stmt := 'BEGIN INPUTPROCEDURE(:LV_CHOICE); END;';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dyn_stmt USING b;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in PL/SQL - PL/SQL doesn't have access to the terminal(unless you do something [like plug in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm#CACJJHGI) or call your program from a [something like SQL*Plus(in which you can use commands like ACCEPT/PROMPT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28105507/92837) before you run the procedure).

The `&` variables are substitution variables, and are specific to SQL*Plus, not PL/SQL